# Use Functor / Predicate to find the first element smaller than its predecessor in vector

Tags: c++, vector, predicate, functor

currently I am trying to use function objects to find the first element that is smaller than the previous element in a vector.
For example I have vector `v` and its contents are `{ 25, 30, 10, 40};`
I tried toying with functors and with the algorithm library, but I can't get a correct result.
My attempt was:

```
auto target = find_if( v.begin( ), v.end( ), &greaterneighbour );
if ( target != v.end( ) )
    cout << target << endl;
```

The functor I tried to implement however was incorrect and only worked with pre-set elements (like comparing each element with 4).
My question is how can I use functors to compare two elements of a vector.

Comment: @TanveerBadar thank you for the fast response, I guess that is my only option.

Comment: I was wrong, there is indeed an algorithm for that too. See the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`std::adjacent_find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) for that.

```
auto iter = std::adjacent_find(begin(v), end(v), [](const auto& a, const auto& b) { return a < b; });
```